# Problem with lists; TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list

```
import random
stats=[]
attributes=5
print("Stats:", end=" ")
for i in range(attributes):
  r=random.randint(40,70)
  stats.append(r)
  print(stats[i], end=" ")
print('''
\t[1]- Strength
\t[2]- Dexterity
\t[3]- Intelligence
\t[4]- Wisdom
\t[5]- Charisma
''')
select = int(input("Select: "))
select -= 1
stats[select] += random.randint(10,15)
for i in range(len(stats)):
  if i==select:
    continue
  stats[i] -= random.randint(10,15)
print(f'''New Stats is: {stats}''', end= " ")

#Fireball
fireball=[12, 15, 28, 10, 5]
skill=input("\nChoose One Of Four Skills: ")
if skill=="F" or "f":
  stats[i] -= fireball[i]
  if stats[i]>0:
    print(stats)
#After this there should be 3 more similar ones (Like same but for lightning).

#Lightning

#Silence

#Fire Ward
```

With this code I get for exaple this output:

```
Stats: 65 48 48 42 41 
    [1]- Strength
    [2]- Dexterity
    [3]- Intelligence
    [4]- Wisdom
    [5]- Charisma

Select: 3
New Stats is: [54, 36, 59, 29, 26] 
Choose One Of Four Skills: f
[54, 36, 59, 29, 21]
```

However, what I expect to see in the last lines is:

```
Choose One Of Four Skills: f
[42, 21, 28, 19, 16]
```

Because I have clearly metioned that the list shoul be decrease by values in list fireball in these lines:

```
if skill=="F" or "f":
      stats[i] -= fireball[i]
```

Could anyone please explain why it gives me the same list? I tried adding `[i]` in the last line (which is: `print(stats)`), but in that case it shows only one value.

Comment: I think you intend to say `if skill.lower() == "f"`, as otherwise you are evaluating the equivalent of `if (skill=="F") or bool("f")`

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `i` from the previous loop. Create a new loop to adjust the stats.

```
#Fireball
fireball=[12, 15, 28, 10, 5]
skill=input("\nChoose One Of Four Skills: ")
if skill=="F" or "f":
  for i in range(len(stats)):
    stats[i] -= fireball[i]
  print(stats)
```

Output

```
Stats: 51 57 54 61 65
        [1]- Strength
        [2]- Dexterity
        [3]- Intelligence
        [4]- Wisdom
        [5]- Charisma

Select: 3
New Stats is: [38, 44, 68, 46, 50]
Choose One Of Four Skills: f
[26, 29, 40, 36, 45]
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you were missing a loop,

```
  for i in range(len(stats)):
    stats[i] -= fireball[i]
  if stats[i]>0:
    print(stats)
```

[image: Here is the output.]